Deploying error at the server for mulesoft project
When I deployed my mule project to the server, the following error occur. It is okay at my local.
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dw:transform-message'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":legacy-abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-info-mapping}' is expected.
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:220) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:64) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:137) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:59) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:72) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:536) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:333) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:325) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:100) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:298) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:156) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:139) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:172) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
    at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:52) ~[mule-module-reboot-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:2788) ~[wrapper-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]

I try to add plugins to the server but it is not fixed yet. how to do and which plugins need?

Does this answer your question? Mule / Maven Error: Invalid content was found starting with element 'dw:transform-message'

If the issue is happening only at the server it probably means that the installation has been corrupted. The DataWeave plugin should be built-in. That should not be a programming error so it would be off topic for Stackoverflow. Note that Mule 3.9 has entered end of life on March 2024. It would be advisable to migrate to a current version of Mule 4.
